# Is there a term that simultaneously captures "dimensionality" and "cardinality"?

Tags: number-theory, terminology

We know that (perhaps counterintuitively for beginners), the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ is the same as that of $\mathbb R^2$, analogous to the fact that the cardinality of $\mathbb N$ is the same as that of $\mathbb Z$.

However, the dimensionality is obviously not the same between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$. Nevertheless it is the same for $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb N^2$, since for both, we need a set of two numbers to describe them.

I am looking for a term that captures that the dimensionality AND the cardinality of two objects are the same. i.e., X and Y have the same **** iff they have the same dimensionality and the same cardinality. Does such a term exist?

Comment: I think probably not. Do you need a term for this idea for something you are writing, or are you just curious? If the former, edit the question to provide more context.

Comment: I am just curious, in the sense that if such a term exists, I might be able to look for stuff on it that's interesting.

Comment: What do you mean by "obviously," [white man](https://huntthedevil.wordpress.com/2015/05/08/what-do-you-mean-we-white-man/)?

Comment: @XanderHenderson, by obviously, I really mean nothing more than, "don't try to explain that to me because that is not what this question is about" :P

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that the heart of your question comes down to what is actually meant by "dimension."  As far as I am concerned, $\mathbb{N}^2$ is zero dimensional (it is a countable union of zero dimensional points, and the Hausdorff dimension is countably stable).  And "number of parameters needed to specify a point" is not nearly rigorous enough---I can describe every point in $\mathbb{N}^2$ with a single number, via an explicit bijection to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, Aren't there different definitions of "dimension" that state that $\mathbb N^2$ has two dimensions? Otherwise what would we call the thing that is $2$ here?

Comment: I'm not sure that I know of any notion of dimension that immediately gives you that $\mathbb{N}^2$ is two-dimensional.  Perhaps if you regard it as a semigroup with two generators, and equate "order" to "dimension"?  (I'm an analyst, not an algebraist, so I'm not even sure that the previous sentence makes sense.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69522/discussion-between-xander-henderson-and-programmer2134).